# Angular 2 - Load JS on demand from server and run within current scope

Tags: javascript, angular, express

I have an Angular 2 app that uses an ExpressJS server as an API.

It requests the endpoint api/games/:id which returns a .js file which I then append to the HTML head within a  tag - this file includes all the javascript needed to run the game.

So lets say the endpoint returns the .js file:

```
var SeedGame = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
__extends(SeedGame, _super);
function SeedGame(width, height, render, id) {
    var _this = _super.call(this, width, height, render, id, null) || this;
    _this.state.add('Boot', BootState, false);
    return _this;
}
return SeedGame;
}(Phaser.Game));

var BootState = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
__extends(BootState, _super);
function BootState() {
    return _super !== null && _super.apply(this, arguments) || this;
}
BootState.prototype.init = function () {
    this.stage.backgroundColor = '#ff0087';
};
BootState.prototype.preload = function () {
};
BootState.prototype.render = function () {};
return BootState;
}(Phaser.State));
```

The problem I am having is that I'd like to not have the code added to the global window object. It would be nice if I could have the returned function included within an angular component scope.

```
this.scriptService.loadScript('api/games/load').then(results2 => {
   // Where id like to access the SeedGame function from the server
 });
```

I have control over the JS returned from the endpoint so will be able to change how it is structured.

Is this possible?